# chmod: missing operand after a+t

Tags: linux, bash, shell

Trying to fix world writable files and getting the error below:

```
chmod: missing operand after a+t
```

here is my code

```
df --local -P | awk {'if (NR!=1) print $6'} | xargs -I '{}' find '{}' -xdev -type d -perm -0002 -a ! -perm -1000 2>/dev/null | xargs chmod a+t
```

Any thoughts?

Comment: If you used `-exec` instead of `xargs` you wouldn't have this problem (or several others).

Comment: If you have GNU `xargs`, you can use the `--no-run-if-empty` (aka `-r`) option to avoid running the command once even when there are no arguments (the behaviour required by POSIX, probably in deference to historical precedent rather than because it seemed like a really good idea).  But you'd do best to avoid using `xargs`.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler  Still calling the command when there are no arguments, why, that is like ... still expanding to the unexpanded glob pattern when it matches nothing, and passing a useless argument.

Comment: @Kaz, ...there's a damned good reason `nullglob` is off-by-default: Widely available command-line programs have default behavior they use when passed no arguments; passing them a glob literal means that instead of falling back on that default behavior, they have an opportunity to emit an error. The default behavior of GNU xargs, by contrast, is something for which I have no defense.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's no need for `xargs` here at all -- it's the source of your bugs, and would be the source of *even more* bugs if you had contents mounted on a directory with spaces or quotes (or literal backslashes) in its name.

```
{
  read _                           # consume header
  while IFS= read -r dirname; do   # ...iterate over later lines...
    find "$dirname" -xdev -type d \
      '(' -perm -0002 -a ! -perm -1000 ')' \
      -exec chmod a+t '{}' + 2>/dev/null
  done
} < <(df --output=target --local)  # tell df to emit only the one column you want
```

---

To clarify *why* xargs is a source of bugs in this code:

- GNU xargs (but not BSD xargs) will call the command with no arguments whatsoever if its input has no contents. This is your immediate problem at hand.
- All POSIX-compliant xargs implementations will parse quotes and backslashes (consuming them), and split input on whitespace unless extensions are used to direct it to do otherwise (such as `-0` [thereby requiring NUL-delimited inputs], or, in the GNU version, `-d $'\n'` [to work correctly with newline delimiters]). This means if you had content mounted at `/media/Movie Name With Spaces`, xargs would be trying to run `find` against `/media/Movie`, `Name`, `With`, and `Spaces` separately; `/media/Movie Name With Spaces "And Quotes"` would do likewise, but with `And Quotes` (lacking the spaces!) as a single word.

Moreover, there's no efficiency benefit to using `xargs` here, if your `find` code is using modern (2006-era) POSIX extensions: `-exec somecommand {} +` passes as many arguments to `somecommand` as will fit on each invocation, just as `xargs somecommand` does.

Answer (score 1):

This happens when you provide no argument to `chmod`:

```
$ chmod a+x
chmod: missing operand after ‘a+x’
Try 'chmod --help' for more information.
```

So presumably, the command:

```
df --local -P | awk {'if (NR!=1) print $6'} | \
        xargs -I '{}' find '{}' -xdev -type d -perm -0002 -a ! -perm -1000 2>/dev/null
```

is not generating any output i.e. you don't have any directory with matching the required `perm` constraints in the given directories to be searched. Run only this command, without `chmod`, to be sure of this.